# removing a div by an onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a div with an onclick event but it's not working and the div stays there, below is the code I am using, anyone can help?

```
<div id="apDiv2">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('apDiv2').removeChild(document.getElementById('apDiv1'))">
        <div id="apDiv1"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: the apDiv2 do not have child apDiv1. You need to reference the a tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div id="apDiv2">

<a href="#" onclick="this.removeChild(this.firstChild)"><div id="apDiv1">T</div></a>

</div>
```

- [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) only removes a direct child.
- I also made the code a bit cleaner:

  - `this` references the event's tag itself (in this case the `<a>` tag)
  - `this.firstChild` points to the first child of the link tag: the `<div id="apDiv1">`

By the way, please take a look in the developer console of your browser (e.g. `F12` in Chrome) the next time. You would have seen an eror which you could post here. It will help people helping you ;)

---

An even better way would be to put the JavaScript in its own file (or at least in a  block) and to use the IDs for referencing the elements.

I'd give the link another ID, say for example `myLink`:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
});
```

In case you cannot specify an ID for the link tag, there are multiple ways for using the outer *apDiv2*  as a reference point, e.g.:

```
var linkTag = document.querySelector("#apDiv2 a");
// or
var linkTag = document.getElementById("apDiv2").getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

Comment: @user2325465 Thanks ;) I also added an explanation for the new code.

Comment: Better, but why keep the inline JavaScript event-handling, given that both `div` elements have an `id` and can be easily targeted?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your input. I've added a sample in case the OP wants to adapt this way.

Comment: @user2325465 Please accept this answer if it helped you. I took a look at your previous questions and it seems that there aren't any accepted answers. [Here is an explanation on this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).